# Photoshop CS6 and .psd Photoshop CC 2014

Tags: adobe-photoshop, save

The project was created with multiple layers (visible or not) in Photoshop CC 2014, then this project has been opened Photoshop CS6.

**PROBLEMS:**

a) When you copy all (*Ctrl + A* **>** *Ctrl + Shift + C*) produces an error: **"Could not complete the Copy Merged command because of a program error."**

b) When you combine all visible in a single layer (*Ctrl + Shift + N* **>** *Ctrl + Shift + Alt + E*) gives an error:: **"Could not complete the Merge Visible command because of a program error."**

c) When I restore of the project to a new location, I get the error: **"Could not save as" ... my path ... "because of a"**

Maybe someone knows how to overcome?

*P.S. in another similar source code - everything is OK.*

Comment: What are you trying to do in CS6?

Comment: @EddieA. I'm trying to accomplish items a, b and c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's all sorts of incompatibility when opening any file in any older program. If all you're trying to do is merge/flatten layers. **I would just do it in CC.**

I don't think you will find another straight forward answer. Things get weird when you try and use 4 year old software.

Comment: Yes, perhaps you're right. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to check this 
=> Look in your Photoshop preferences folder for the file PSErrorLog.txt (Contains error logs but not all errors).

I have been looking for this and i found this solution works for me :

1.Change the language format in the EDIT >> Preferences >> Type from East Asia to Middle Eastern.

2. Try to open your file into another PC or Laptop having PS recommended specifications for hardware because it might be RAM problem or in memory
3. Use some cleaning tool for remove temp memory generated by PS and also to reset the settings of PS.

Hope that helped